# Significato di "nel tempo" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *La novella dell’apprendista esattore* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto questo dialogo:

> – Un momento, – disse forte il maresciallo. – Qualcuno di voi per caso ha parlato con lui? 
>         
>   – Amedeo, – dissero in tanti. 
>         – Io, maresciallo, – sospirò Amedeo. Il maresciallo gli accennò di accostarsi. – E che impressione vi ha fatto? 
>         – Non so dire. Non ho potuto capir bene. 
>         – Deciso a tutto? 
>         – Forse. 
>          – Anche contro di noi? 
>         – Chissà, maresciallo. 
>         – Allora è pazzo, – concluse il maresciallo. – Lo è sempre stato? 
>         – È sempre stato… speciale, – disse Amedeo. 
>         – Pazzi in famiglia? – proseguí il maresciallo. – Risultano consanguinei ricoverati **nel tempo** in manicomio? 
>         – No, che io sappia no. 
>         – No, no, – confermarono risentiti alcuni dei piú vicini. 
>         – Si chiama Davide Cora, vero? 
>         – Sí, maresciallo. Fu Vincenzo.

Ho cercato alla voce "tempo" in parecchi dizionari e ho trovato alcuni esempi di uso dell'espressione "nel tempo", come nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tempo/), ma nessuno di questa locuzione usata in modo assoluto come nel brano sopra citato. Allora, la mia domanda è: qual è il significato di questo "nel tempo" che appare nel testo? Vuol dire forse "nel tempo presente", "in questo momento"? O il significato sarebbe piuttosto "lungo il tempo", "attraverso il tempo", cioè, il maresciallo sta chiedendo se ci sono stati antenati di Davide Cora ricoverati in manicomio?

Comment: Concordo con l'ultima interpretazione - significa _nel corso del tempo_

Answer (score 2):

Nel contesto da te citato l'espressione ***nel tempo*** significa *nel corso del tempo*, *precedentemente*. Viene quindi in questo caso stabilito un intervallo aperto verso il passato e chiuso sul presente.

Il  maresciallo sta effettivamente chiedendo se ci sono stati antenati di Davide Cora ricoverati precedentemente in manicomio.